# Should I use an Interface in this code?

Tags: java, interface

I have the following simple classes

```
public class Athlete
{
    int Code;
    String Name;
    String Surname;
    Date DateOfBirth;

    public Athlete() {}
}

public class Game
{
    int Code;
    String Gamename;
    Date DateOfGame;

    public Game() {}
}

public class Participates
{
    int Code;
    Game game;
    Athlete athlete;
    float Performance;
    boolean Valid;

    public Participates() {}
}
```

Would it be better if I declared the Participates class as an Interface implemented by Athlete or is it fine that way? (Athlete can participate on many Games)

**EDIT 1:** This is a sample of my code, just to make my point

**EDIT 2:** My question is about optimization of this code, so changes to fields and methods are not prohibited if needed

Comment: Not sure what you mean... the `Participates` class *cannot* be an interface, as it doesn't have only instance methods (it has fields as well).

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  You've defined the relationship between `Athlete` and `Game` in the `Participates` class, although I'd probably give it a noun name like Participation.

Comment: Couple things: first off, the Java "standard" is to have getters and setters wrap your instance variables. This makes it easier to change things later on if some logic needs to happen to validate the state of things (which you can't do with method access). Second, then, assuming you've done that, the answer is no: it is generally considered best practice for these kind of classes to not have interfaces.

Comment: Interfaces are used for **is-a** relationship. So is an Athlete a Participates? No, Athlete is not a Participates =)

Comment: Ok I think i got it now, thanks all
(as for setters, getters I didnt add them in my question to keep it small)
And since Interface are used to describe behavior I thought I could use it to describe Participation as a behavior. Maybe the name is not optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider decomposing your object model based on things that are:

1. Role
2. Description
3. Party, Place or Thing
4. Moment or interval (e.g. an event)

Then consider composition for a particular object and use interface for methods that multiple object types might reasonable implement.

You have an `Athelete` class (perhaps should be a role for a `person`, since you may have an `referee` sometime too). You have a `Game` class (looks good it is a thing, looks like it contains an event (when the game occurs).

You defined a participates class .. this does NOT look like a good class. You seem to want to encapsulate the participants in a game .. which is something that would be handled better by a method.

**Game Class (includes isParticipant method)**

```
package com.example.athletics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class Game {
    // Object fields
    int code;
    String name;
    Date gameDate; // perhaps an interval would be better here

    ArrayList<Athlete> players;


    public Game() {
        players = new ArrayList<Athlete>();
    };

    public void addPlayer(Athlete athlete) {
        players.add(athlete);
    }

    public boolean isParticipant(Athlete athlete) {
        // TODO improve performance by creating a HashMap perhaps?

        boolean result = false;
        for (int i=0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            if (athlete.equals(players.get(i))) {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Athlete Class**

```
package com.example.athletics;

import java.util.Date;

public class Athlete {
// Object fields
    int code;
    String Name;
    String surName;
    Date birthDate;

    public Athlete(){}
    // TODO methods to identify the Athlete

    public boolean equals(Athlete other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return code == other.getCode();
        }
    }

    public int getCode() {return code;}
}
```

Comment: I think I like your implementation. I will work on it. Thank you for your insight. As for Person superclass there is one, as there is one for Sport (I will use Game as a single event). I just wrote what needed to make my case

Answer (score 1):

An interface should be used to describe behaviour. That is not the case on Participate or any of these classes, that have no methods.

Use an interface when you want to force the classes that implement it to have a particular set of methods.

However, interfaces are a concept that only makes sense, when you have an application developed by different teams at different stages, or using certain frameworks. If you're going to develop an application by yourself on a single session, without using any framework, probably it makes no sense to use them. Unless you want to do it as an exercise.

Comment: The way i declared my classes, I needed fields like performance and valid and no methods. I should be more clear and ask if it was better to declare it as an Interface, not the way it is now but reformed.
Thank you for your suggestion on solo development, I will keep that in mind :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an interface, but you rather need to extend Athlete off of Participate(s). If an Athlete is a participant in a race, shouldn't Athlete inherit Participate(s)? It seems logical.

You could also just make Participate a class without any inheritors and just use that to represent athletes and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any plan to create two implementations, don't add an interface.

If you find out later that you need a second implementation, use refactoring to extract an interface, and add a second implementation.